# Who produced the first permanent horseshoe magnet: Johann Dietrich or Gilles-Augustin Bazin?

Tags: magnetism

Several recent sources state that the first known permanent horseshoe magnet was produced by the instrument maker **Johann Dietrich** of Basel, probably in 1743. However, several older French sources claim that the first horseshoe magnet was invented by **Gilles-Augustin Bazin** of Strasbourg.

<sup>There is some uncertainty over whether Dietrich produced these magnets so on his own, or at the suggestion of Daniel Bernoulli. That controversy is the subject of [another question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/15191/permanent-horseshoe-magnet-primary-sources-of-information-about-its-invention) of mine here at HSM StackExchange. For what it's worth, given what I know at present, I think that Dietrich came up with the idea on his own.</sup>

### The case for Bazin

1. In [*Dictionnaire d'électricité et de magnétisme*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dictionnaire_d_%C3%A9lectricit%C3%A9_et_de_magn/vQI_AAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) from 1887, we find the following entries. First [this](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dictionnaire_d_%C3%A9lectricit%C3%A9_et_de_magn/vQI_AAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA9&printsec=frontcover&dq=AIMANT%20en%20fer%20%C3%A0%20cheval%20):

> **AIMANT en fer à cheval (*Hufeisenmagnet* —— Horseshoe magnet).**
>  Barreau
> aimanté, recourbé en forme de fer à cheval , de manière que les deux
> pôles soient rapprochés et qu'il en résulte une modification dans la
> forme du champ magnétique . Les lignes de force unissant les deux
> pôles étant raccourcies, le champ de force est diminué, comme
> dimensions, mais augmenté proportionnellement en intensité. On regarde
> Bazin (Voir ce mot) , comme l'inventeur de cette disposition
> avantageuse<sup>1</sup>. Le Dr Rosenberger en attribue le mérite à
> Johann Dietrich de Bâle<sup>2</sup>. La force portante des aimants en
> fer à cheval est a $\sqrt[3]{P^{2}}$. $P$ est le poids de l'aimant et
> a un facteur constant qui, pour les aimants de Häcker, était égal à 10
> .
>  
>  <sup><sup>1</sup>BRISSON, *Principes de physique,* t. III,
> p. 226 (an VIII).</sup>
>  <sup><sup>2</sup>Rosenberger, *Die
> Geschichte der Physik,* vol . II, p . 297.</sup>

Translation via Google Translate:

> **HORSESHOE MAGNET (*Hufeisenmagnet* —— Horseshoe magnet).**
>  Magnetic
> bar, bent in the shape of a horseshoe, so that the two poles are
> brought together and this results in a modification in the shape of
> the magnetic field. The lines of force uniting the two poles being
> shortened, the field of force is diminished in size, but
> proportionally increased in intensity. Bazin (See this word) is
> regarded as the inventor of this advantageous arrangement 1 . Dr.
> Rosenberger credits Johann Dietrich of Basel 2. The bearing strength
> of horseshoe magnets is $\sqrt[3]{P^{2}}$. $P$ is the weight of the
> magnet and has a constant factor which for Häcker magnets was equal to
> 10.
>  
>  <sup><sup>1</sup>BRISSON, *Principes de physique,* t. III, p. 226 (an VIII).</sup>
>  <sup><sup>2</sup>Rosenberger, *Die
> Geschichte der Physik,* vol . II, p . 297.</sup>

The reference to Brisson will be discussed as the next source in this section, while the Rosenberger reference will be discussed in the section "The case for Dietrich."

Then, in the same source, [this](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Dictionnaire_d_%C3%A9lectricit%C3%A9_et_de_magn/vQI_AAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA33&printsec=frontcover&dq=Gilles-Augustin):

> **BAZIN (Gilles -Augustin).** Médecin français, fixé à Strasbourg, où il est mort en mars 1754. Il était né à Paris et était correspondant
> de l'Académie des sciences. C'est à lui que l'on doit la disposition
> de l'aimant dite en fer à cheval ( Voir BRISSON, Physique mathématique
> (an VIII, t . III , p . 226). Il n'a publié que deux mémoires sur la
> description des courants magnétiques, datés de Strasbourg 1753-1754.

Translation via Google Translate:

> **BAZIN (Gilles-Augustin).** French doctor, settled in Strasbourg, where he died in March 1754. He was born in Paris and was a
> correspondent of the Academy of Sciences. It is to him that we owe the
> so-called horseshoe arrangement of the magnet (See BRISSON,
> Mathematical Physics (an VIII, t. III, p. 226). He published only two
> memoirs on the description of magnetic currents, dated from Strasbourg
> 1753-1754.

2. The Brisson reference, *Traité élémentaire ou principes de physique,* Volume 3 (1799) is available [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Trait%C3%A9_%C3%A9l%C3%A9mentaire_ou_principes_de_ph/0Y82isvXnCUC?hl=en&gbpv=0). The relevant section is [as follows](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Trait%C3%A9_%C3%A9l%C3%A9mentaire_ou_principes_de_ph/0Y82isvXnCUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22premier%20ex%C3%A9cut%C3%A9%20Bazin%20de%20Strasbourg%22&pg=PA226&printsec=frontcover):

> L'on peut donner aux aimans artificiels telle forme que l'on veut ; ce
> que l'on ne peut pas toujours faire aux aimans naturels. On en peut
> faire en demi-cercle (fig. 318), en fer à cheval (fig. 319), etc. et
> leur faire alors , au moyen d'un portant P, soutenir un poids plus
> considérable , en faisant agir les deux poles à la fois. C'est ce qu'a
> le premier exécuté Bazin de Strasbourg.

Translation via Google Translate:

> You can give artificial magnets any shape you want; which cannot
> always be done to natural magnets. It can be made in a semicircle
> (fig. 318), in a horseshoe (fig. 319), etc., and then make them, by
> means of a bearing P, support a more considerable weight, by making
> the two poles act at the same time. This is what Bazin of Strasbourg
> first executed.

3. In *L'Intermédiaire des chercheurs et curieux* of [30 décembre 1891](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/RyIFAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0), we find [this](https://www.google.com/books/edition/L_interm%C3%A9diaire_des_chercheurs_et_curie/RyIFAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA1031&printsec=frontcover&dq=Bazin):

> **L'histoire des aimants.­** —— On attribue généralement l'invention des aimants en fer à cheval à Bazin (1), de Strasbourg, ou à Johann
> Dietrich (2), de Bâle.
>
> Le premier en publia le dessin, en 1753, dans un ouvrage curieux et
> rare (3) sur les *Courants magnétiques* où il étudie le spectre
> magnétique des différentes formes d'aimant.
>
> Il est fait mention de cette forme dans des ouvrages antérieurs (4).
>
> Un chercheur pourrait- il nous indiquer le premier ouvrage dans lequel
> ces aimants sont décrits?
>
> (1) Brisson, *Physique,* III, p. 226, in-8 (an VIII); Jacquez,
> *Dictionnaire d'Electricité,* in-8 (1887).
>  (2) Rosenberger, *die Geschichte der Physik,* t. II, p. 297 (1887).
>  (3) Bazin,
> *Description des courants magnétiques,* in-4 ( 1753).
>  (4) Mitchell, *Treatise on artificial magnets,* In-8 (1750).

Translation via Google Translate:

> **The History of Magnets.** —— The invention of horseshoe magnets is generally attributed to Bazin (1) from Strasbourg or Johann Dietrich
> (2) from Basel.
>
> The first published drawing, in 1753, in a curious and rare work (3)
> on *Magnetic currents* where he studies the magnetic spectrum of the
> different forms of magnet.
>
> Mention is made of this form in earlier works (4) .
>
> Could a researcher tell us the first book in which these magnets are
> described?
>
> (1) Brisson, *Physique,* III, p. 226, in-8 (an VIII); Jacquez,
> *Dictionnaire d'Electricité,* in-8 (1887).
>  (2) Rosenberger, *die*
> *Geschichte der Physik,* vol. II, p. 297 (1887).
>  (3) Bazin,
> *Description des courants magnétiques,* in-4 ( 1753).
>  (4) Mitchell,
> *Treatise on artificial magnets,* In-8 (1750).

I looked at the later issues of this magazine, and, unfortunately, this query seems to have gone unanswered.

The reference "Jacquez, *Dictionnaire d'Electricité*" is the first reference I gave, above. The Brisson reference I already discussed, while the Rosenberger one I will discuss below. I will soon also discuss Bazin's publication.

Mitchell's treatise is available [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Treatise_of_Artificial_Magnets/C4o5AAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0). It mentions horseshoe magnets, but it doesn't mention who invented them. In particular, it doesn't mention either Dietrich, or Bazin, or Bernoulli. Indeed, it is quite possible that by 1750, the horseshoe magnet had been invented in Great Britain independently. This would be consistent with the remark of Radelet-de Grave's (see below) that *It is difficult to date the apparition of the horseshoe magnets, which, moreover, were discovered independently in England later on.*

4. In *Traité élémentaire de physique théorique et expérimentale avec les applications à la météorologie et aux arts industriels à l'usage des Facultés, des établissements d'enseignement secondaire et des écoles spéciales du Gouvernement* by P. A. Daguin, published in 1861, in the entry "Magnétisme," we find [this statement](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Trait%C3%A9_%C3%A9l%C3%A9mentaire_de_physique_th%C3%A9or/QGUJr6u0a_kC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22M.%20Bazin%20a%20eu%20l%27id%C3%A9e%22&pg=PA49&printsec=frontcover):

> M. Bazin a eu l'idée de recourber un seul barreau aimanté, en forme de
> fer à cheval, de manière à faire agir les deux pôles sur un même
> portant.

Translation via Google Translate:

> Mr. Bazin had the idea of bending a single magnetic bar, in the shape
> of a horseshoe, so as to make the two poles act on the same bearing [or 'support'].

5. In the article "Un savant Barrisien précurseur de M. Pasteur: Louis Joblot (1645-1723)" ("A Barrisian scholar, precursor of Mr. Pasteur: Louis Joblot (1645-1723)") by  W. Konarski, published in Mémoires de la Société des lettres, sciences et arts de Bar-le-Duc., Troisième Série, Tome IV, p. 205 (1895), we find [this](https://www.google.com/books/edition/M%C3%A9moires_de_la_Soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9_des_lettres_sc/lrcjAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA311&printsec=frontcover&dq=%20fer%20%C3%A0%20cheval%20de%20Bazin.) (boldface emphasis mine):

> Ce mode d'enseignement oral, auquel nous l'avons vu empressé à
> recourir pour traiter, sous le patronage de l'Académie de Peinture,
> des sujets d'un ordre tout autre, Joblot ne l'aurait-il pas employé
> tout aussi volontiers, ce qui expliquerait la rareté de ses écrits sur
> la physique, pour vulgariser autour de lui ses doctrines et ses
> procédés en matière de magnétisme?  Quoi qu'il en ait pu être, et sans
> dissimuler qu'à travers les aberrations théoriques de ceux qui
> l'avaient précédé dans cette voie —Gilbert, le P. Kircher, Descartes,
> Rohault, Hartsoeker— il a pu et a dû puiser d'utiles renseignements
> pratiques, le peu que nous avons de lui suffit à dénoter un
> observateur attentif et pénétrant, un constructeur ingénieux pour le
> temps où il vécut .Les dispositions essentielles de son appareil sont
> demeurées classiques pendant toute la première moitié du XVII° siècle
> **avant que de céder la place au fer à cheval de Bazin.** Nombre de ses indications sommaires sur les procédés de friction, sur les formes
> et les proportions à donner aux barreaux, sur les soins à apporter à
> leur ajustage se retrouvent, longtemps après lui, avec plus de
> développements peut-être, sous la plume de Réaumur, de Le Monnier, de
> Buffon, de Nollet, de Brisson.

Translation via Google Translate:

> This mode of oral teaching, to which we have seen him eager to resort
> to treat, under the patronage of the Academy of Painting, subjects of
> an entirely different order, Joblot would not have employed it just as
> willingly, which would explain the rarity of his writings on physics,
> to popularize around him his doctrines and his methods in the matter
> of magnetism? Whatever it may have been, and without concealing that
> through the theoretical aberrations of those who had preceded him on
> this path—Gilbert, Father Kircher, Descartes, Rohault, Hartsoeker—he
> was able and had to draw useful practical information, the little that
> we have of him is enough to denote an attentive and penetrating
> observer, an ingenious builder for the time in which he lived. The
> essential arrangements of his apparatus remained classic throughout
> the first half of the seventeenth century, **before giving way to the
> horseshoe of Bazin.** Many of his summary indications on the processes
> of friction, on the shapes and proportions to be given to the bars, on
> the care to be taken in their adjustment are found, long after him,
> with perhaps more developments, under the pen of Réaumur, Le Monnier,
> Buffon, Nollet, Brisson.

6. Bazin's work seems to be described in *Le Journal des Sçavans* of Dec. 1753, [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Journal_des_s%C3%A7avans/5uE0mqCTv9gC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22DESCRIPTION%20DES%20COURANS%20MAGNETIQUES%22&pg=PA771&printsec=frontcover). It does mention Bazin experimenting with horseshoe-shaped magnets, but it doesn't say when this might have happened. The relevant section is [this](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Journal_des_s%C3%A7avans/5uE0mqCTv9gC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22fer%20%C3%A0%20cheval%22&pg=PA774&printsec=frontcover)

> Il a quelquefois rassemblé trois aimans artificiels, & il en ia a
> formé un triangle. Sa curiosité ne s'est pas encore trouvé satisfaite
> par ces différentes combinaisons , il a donné aux morceaux d'acier sur
> lesquels il faisoit ses expériences, la forme de cercle ou d'anneau,
> celle d'un fer à cheval, celle de la Lettre S.

Translation via Google Translate:

> He [Bazin] has sometimes gathered together three artificial magnets,
> and from them he has formed a triangle. His curiosity has not yet been
> satisfied by these different combinations, he gave to the pieces of
> steel on which he made his experiments, the shape of a circle or a
> ring, that of a horseshoe, that of the Letter S.

Bazin's 1753 publication *Description des courants magnétiques, dessinés et gravés d'aprés nature en XV planches, suivie de quelques observations sur l'aiman* *(Description of the magnetic currents, drawn and engraved from nature in 15 plates, followed by some observations on the magnet)* is available [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Description_des_courants_magn%C3%A9tiques_de/EtuWwEcplgEC?hl=en&gbpv=0), with the supplement (containing all the figures) [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/_/Mds-ODnEnoYC?hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj63-yvgb39AhWbD1kFHQ6ADZwQ7_IDegQIFBAC).

Bazin is mentioned in English-language sources, e.g. in [*A new general biographical dictionary, projected and partly arranged by H.J. Rose*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_new_general_biographical_dictionary_pr/1yoAAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA410&printsec=frontcover&dq=Courans), although that source doesn't say Bazin was the inventor of the horseshoe magnet. The same biographical dictionary [doesn't mention](https://archive.org/details/b24870134_0007/page/78/mode/2up) Dietrich of Basel, and doesn't mention horseshoe magnets in its [entry for Daniel Bernoulli](https://archive.org/details/b24870134_0004/page/160/mode/2up).

### The case for Dietrich

What follows are the same sources I used in my [other question](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/15191/permanent-horseshoe-magnet-primary-sources-of-information-about-its-invention). For completeness, I am going to repeat them here.

1. Ferdinand Rosenberger, *Die Geschichte Der Physik in Grundzügen* *(The history of physics in outline),* vol. 2 (F. Vieweg und sohn, Braunschweig, Germany, 1884), p. 297, available [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Die_Geschichte_Der_Physik_in_Grundz%C3%BCgen/nv04AAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0). This is the reference given in several sources mentioned above (although I should note that this is an earlier edition than referenced above, 1884 as opposed to 1887). The relevant section (the only one where either Dietrich or horseshoe magnets are mentioned) is [this](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Die_Geschichte_Der_Physik_in_Grundz%C3%BCgen/nv04AAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22um%20diese%20Zeit%20der%20Baseler%20Mechaniker%22&pg=RA1-PA297&printsec=frontcover):

> Die Inclinationsboussole selbst suchten Daniel Bernoulli und Euler zu
> verbessern, indem sie die Bedingungen untersuchten , unter welchen die
> verschiedenen Inclinationsnadeln übereinstimmende Resultate ergeben
> mussten. Bernoulli erhielt für die betreffende Arbeit 1743 den Preis
> der Pariser Akademie , Euler das Accessit. Vielleicht auch auf
> Veranlassung Daniel Bernoulli's führte um diese Zeit der Baseler
> Mechaniker Johann Dietrich († 1758) die Ilufeisenmagnete und ihre
> Armirung ein; wenigstens entdeckte Bernoulli mit solchen
> Dietrich'schen Magneten das Gesetz, dass die Tragkraft der
> Hufeisenmagnete proportional ist ihren Oberflächen oder den dritten
> Wurzeln aus den Quadraten ihrer Gewichte.

Translation via Google Translate, plus *Boussole* = *compass* (see [here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bussole)) and *Accessit* assumed to be *Ak­zes­sit* = *second place prize* (see [here](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Akzessit)):

> The inclination compass itself sought to be improved by Daniel
> Bernoulli and Euler by investigating the conditions under which the
> various inclination needles must give consistent results. In 1743,
> Bernoulli received the prize of the Paris Academy for the work in
> question, and Euler received the second place prize. Perhaps also at
> the instigation of Daniel Bernoulli, the Basel mechanic Johann
> Dietrich († 1758) introduced iron magnets and their armouring around
> this time; at least Bernoulli discovered the law with such Dietrich
> magnets that the lifting capacity of the horseshoe magnets is
> proportional to their surface areas or the third root of the square of
> their weights.

2. Forbes and Dijksterhuis, [*A History of Science and Technology,* Vol. 2](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_History_of_Science_and_Technology/xq7aAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) (1963). The relevant section reads [(see here)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22At+Daniel+Bernoulli%27s+suggestion%22&tbm=bks&ei=ItL4Y4ipIJ6hptQPvaq5qAI),

> The first kind of magnets used were chiefly bar magnets. At Daniel
> Bernoulli's suggestion, the Basle instrument-maker Johann Dietrich
> bent the bar so as to bring the poles close together, thus creating
> the first horseshoe magnet.

This source says that the horseshoe shape was Daniel Bernoulli's idea. At present, this seems unlikely to me, because Daniel Bernoulli himself said otherwise in his *Remarques sur les Aimans artificiels de Basle (Remarks on the artificial magnets of Basel)* Nouvelle Bibliothèque germanique janv. fev. mars 1755. It is available [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Nouvelle_biblioth%C3%A8que_germanique_former/3WgEAAAAQAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q=Bernoulli&f=false). I will now reproduce the relevant section, which starts on p. 225:

> C'est Mr. Dietrich, Bourgeois de cette Ville & habile Artiste, qui
> fait ces Aimans artificiels. Sa curiosité naturelle le porta d'abord à
> construire quelques-uns de ces Aimans, en suivant les préceptes
> connus, & fa capacité le conduisit bientôt à les perfectionner. Il a
> remarqué que la figure la plus convenable pour donner beaucoup de
> force à ces Aimans  est celle d'un fer à cheval: voici la mesure des
> parties d'un de mes Aimans, qui pése 9 1⁄2 onces, & qui porte 16
> livres: …

Here is the output of Google translate (except for *Bourgeois,* meaning *citizen*; the boldfaced emphasis is mine):

> It is Mr. Dietrich, a Citizen of this city and a skillful Artist, who makes
> these artificial magnets; his natural curiosity first led him to
> construct some of these magnets, following the known precepts, and his
> ability soon led him to perfect them. **He has noticed that the figure
> most suitable for giving much force to these magnets is that of a
> horseshoe.** Here is the measurement of the parts of one of my magnets
> which weighs 9 1/2 ounces, and which bears 16. pounds: …

3. Radelet-de Grave, "Studies of Magnetism in the Correspondence of Daniel Bernoulli," in [*Two Cultures: Essays in Honour of David Speiser,*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Two_Cultures/voFsJ1EhCnYC?hl=en&gbpv=0) K. Williams, ed. (Birkhäuser, Basel, 2006).
   Here are the relevant sections:

> In the meantime, Daniel Bernoulli is using horseshoe-shaped magnets,
> invented<sup>24</sup> and produced by Dietrich, in order to determine
> his law giving the magnitude of the force of such a magnet. In several
> letters he reports an empiric law, which was later published in a rather
> peculiar text meant to promote the trade of Dietrich’s magnets: it is rather
> like a commercial advertisement.<sup>25</sup>
>
> <sup><sup>24</sup>It is difficult to date the apparition of the
> horseshoe magnets, which, moreover, were discovered independently in
> England later on. The publication meant to promote their trade is of
> 1755. But they are mentioned in the letters earlier than that: Daniel Bernoulli to Johann Jacob Huber (7 June 1754) and to Pierre Bouguer
> (11 November 1754). In the latter D. Bernoulli says that he has been
> disgusted by this kind of research but he does not give reason
> why.</sup>
> <sup><sup>25</sup>Text R</sup>

The "Text R" is Daniel Bernoulli's *Remarques sur les Aimans artificiels de Basle,* which I already discussed above.

The additional two letters mentioned by Radelet-de Grave are available at swisscollections.ch.

The letter to Johann Jacob Huber is available [here](https://swisscollections.ch/Record/991170514764705501). Since I don't speak French, I transcribed it using [Transkribus](https://readcoop.eu/transkribus/), and then used a combination of ChatGPT and Google translate to correct as best as I could the inevitable (i) errors in transcription and (ii) typos in the original, and then produce an English translation. Here is my current best guess as to the original intended text and its translation:

> Si l'aimant artificiel en forme de fer à cheval et les petites barres
> appartiennent à la Chambre de Physique, car il me semble les avoir
> payées, je prie Mr Huber de les remettre à ma servante. Je serai chez
> moi cet après-midi jusqu'à 3 heures.

Translation:

> If the artificial magnet in the shape of a horseshoe and the small
> bars belong to the Physics Chamber, as I seem to have paid for them, I
> ask Mr. Huber to give them to my servant. I will be at home this
> afternoon until 3 o'clock.

Bernoulli's letter to Pierre Bouguer can be found [here](https://swisscollections.ch/Record/991170514765105501). Using the same procedure as for the previous letter, here is my current best guess for the relevant part of it and its translation:

> Mon observation que la force des aimants artificiels semblables en
> figure et en surfaces suit la raison de la surface de ces aimants
> s'est trouvé confirmée par tous les essais que j'en ai faits. Je
> pourrais bien faire avec le fer les expériences que vous me proposez,
> si j'en reprenais le goût; mais j'en ai été tellement dégoûté que je
> me suis défait de tous les aimants artificiels que j'avais pour ne
> plus les avoir sous mes yeux. J'en ai remis un petit à M. Falckner
> pour l'autoriser d'autant plus à vous voir.

Translation:

> My observation that the force of artificial magnets similar in shape
> and surface is proportional to the surface area of these magnets has
> been confirmed by all the experiments I have conducted. I could
> perform the experiments you propose using iron if I regained an
> interest in them; however, I was so disgusted that I got rid of all
> the artificial magnets I had so that I no longer see them in front of
> my eyes. I gave a small one to Mr. Falckner to encourage him to visit
> you more often.

So far, my most believable source for 1743 being the year when Dietrich made the first horseshoe magnet is the following.

4. *Verhandlungen der Naturforschenden Gesellschaft in Basel,* Volumes 24-25 (available for free [here](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Verhandlungen_der_Naturforschenden_Gesel/gpWSsbJAXPUC?hl=en&gbpv=0)). The relevant section, whose translation by Google translate I don't completely understand, is this:

> In der Festrede zur Feier des 50jährigen Bestehens der Basler
> Naturforschenden Gesellschaft (vom 4. Mai 1867, Verh. IV, Anhang )
> sprach er über die Arbeiten der Societas physica helvetica , der
> Vorgängerin der Gesellschaft , nicht über die Geschichte dieser
> selbst, denn , da die Gründer und Erbauer derselben zugegen waren, „
> ich habe die Überzeugung, dass es den betreffenden, unter uns hochver
> ehrten Männern erwünschter ist, das Rühmliche getan zu haben , als das
> Getane rühmen zu hören ." Der Nachweis, dass die beste Form der
> Inklinationsnadel der Hufeisenmagnet sei, wie 1743 Dan. Bernoulli in
> einer Preisschrift bewies, diese aber vom Goldschmied und
> Instrumentenmacher Joh. Dietrich in Basel zuerst konstruiert worden
> ist , wie Burckhardt nachweist, dürfte daraus am meisten
> interessieren.

Here, for what it's worth, is a translation by Google translate:

> In the speech to celebrate the 50th anniversary of the Basler
> Naturforschenden Gesellschaft (May 4, 1867, Verh. IV , Appendix ) he
> spoke about the work of the Societas physica helvetica , the
> predecessor of the society , not about the history of this itself,
> because , there the founders and builders of the same were present, "
> I am convinced that it is more desirable for the men in question, who
> are highly respected among us, to have done what is creditable than to
> hear praise for what has been done." The proof that the best form of
> the inclination needle the horseshoe magnet is, as Dan Bernoulli
> proved in a prize paper in 1743, but this was first constructed by the
> goldsmith and instrument maker Joh. Dietrich in Basel, as Burckhardt
> proves, should be of most interest.

### Summary of what I know so far

There seems to be no reason to doubt that both Bazin and Dietrich produced their horseshoe magnets independently of each other. Bazin did so no later than 1753.  Dietrich did it definitely no later than 1754, and most likely as early as 1743. Moreover, horseshoe magnets were known in England by 1750, where they had possibly been independently invented by then.

### Question

What is the best current evidence on who came up with the permanent horseshoe magnet first: Bazin or Dietrich? (Or were they perhaps first invented in Great Britain?)

Comment: Just a short comment to a long long question : since Middle Ages, there were many many connections using Rhine river between Basel and Strasbourg eased by a short distance (about 100 km)

Comment: Some questioners on hsm get criticised for not doing prior research. This question is clearly based on an awesomely large quantity of research, and I respect that very much.  On the other hand (and not a remark intended negatively at all), the quantity of existing information found and presented may perhaps also mean there will be fewer potential authors of an answer.